# In JDeveloper, how can I connect to a UDDI v3 registry?

Tags: jdeveloper, uddi, juddi

I would like to use JDeveloper to connect to a jUDDIv3 registry running on JBoss SOA.

I tried:

1. File > New
2. Business Tier > Web Services > UDDI Registry Connection
3. Inquiry Endpoint URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/juddiv3/services/inquiry`
4. Perspective: Business View
5. Test Connection

The status box contained the following:

```
Testing connection with no proxy...
Contacting http://127.0.0.1:8080/juddiv3/services/inquiry
The inquiry endpoint could not be contacted. Test Failed.
Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:&quot;urn:uddi-org:api_v2&quot;, local:&quot;name&quot;). Expected elements are &lt;{urn:uddi-org:api_v3}name&gt;,&lt;{urn:uddi-org:api_v3}authInfo&gt;,&lt;{urn:uddi-org:api_v3}discoveryURLs&gt;,&lt;{urn:uddi-org:api_v3}categoryBag&gt;,&lt;{urn:uddi-org:api_v3}findQualifiers&gt;,&lt;{urn:uddi-org:api_v3}find_relatedBusinesses&gt;,&lt;{urn:uddi-org:api_v3}tModelBag&gt;,&lt;{urn:uddi-org:api_v3}identifierBag&gt;
```

The server log shows the same unmarshalling error. It appears as though JDeveloper is trying to use the v2 api when the registry is expecting v3 calls.

The JDeveloper docs don't seem to have anything on switching the apis, nor have I found anything useful on the internet (so far).

Any ideas on how I can fix this problem?

Thanks,

*Griff*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't. JDeveloper 11g only supports UDDI v2. Apache jUDDIv3 implements only UDDI v3, and does not provide implementations for v2 or v1.

Apache jUDDI v2 implements the UDDI v2 spec, and Apache jUDDI v3 implements the v3 spec.

I don't recommend using Apache jUDDI v2.

References:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/juddi-user/201101.mbox/%3C4D2C6691.1050208@gmail.com%3E

Oracle Fusion Middleware Concepts Guide for Oracle Infrastructure Web Services 11g Release 1 (11.1.1)
Introducing Oracle Infrastructure Web Services
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e15184/intro.htm

Answer (score 1):

jUDDI 3.2, which will be released shortly, has endpoints for UDDIv2. This should help with the interop issues with IDE tools such as Eclipses Web Tools Explorer and JDeveloper. The code is in the trunk, so if you don't want to wait, check out the code from svn and build it using maven.

Edit: it's out now. give it a shot!